# python subprocess store each line of output in a list

Tags: python, subprocess, line-by-line

I'm trying to store the dimensions of video files in a folder into a list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# src_dimensions.py

# requires mediainfo package

import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%x%Height%\n" /home/saad/Videos/*.*', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
   print line
```

The resulting output of this program is:

```
384x288640x480480x350352x162480x360640x360480x360384x288240x180320x240480x360384x288346x26
```

When I run the `mediainfo` command in the terminal, each video dimension is on a newline:

```
384x288
640x480
480x350
352x162
480x360
```

I want each dimension stored as a seperate item in a list. I'm trying to iterate over `stdout` but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE #1**

```
import subprocess
dim = []
proc = subprocess.Popen('mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%x%Height%\\n" /home/saad/Videos/*.*', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
   dim.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
print dim
```

This seems to give me the list, thanks to @Chakib's suggestion.

```
['440x360', '320x240', '480x360', '320x240', '480x360', '320x240', '320x240', '400x224', '']
```

Comment: you habe to escape `\n` in your Popen call like this `\\n`

Comment: works with \\n but output has an extra newline between items e.g.
`340X480`
\n
`480X240`

Comment: How would I do it if my command looked like `itemsListEXT = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True,executable="/bin/bash").splitlines()
    return itemsListEXT`

Comment: answered my own question. it is easy (just change splitlines() to split(): `itemsListEXT = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True,executable="/bin/bash").split()
    return itemsListEXT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\Is this what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# src_dimensions.py
# requires mediainfo package
import subprocess, glob
globpattern = 'path/to/*.*'
cmd = ['mediainfo', '--Inform=Video;%Width%x%Height%\\n']
cmd.extend(glob.glob(globpattern))
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
outputlines = filter(lambda x:len(x)>0,(line.strip() for line in proc.stdout))
print outputlines
```

Comment: Returns: `['480x360480x350320x240384x288640x4801280x720450x360480x3601280x720']`. I want `['480x360', '480x350'...]`

Comment: sounds like a problem in the cmdline arguments.